Applicability domain for multitask learning
Given a multitask machine learning model with several endpoints, I want to determine whether an unseen datapoint is in the applicability domain. I will calculate the tanimoto similarity coefficient and SALI index. My question is, when I calculate these, do I consider my entire training data, or only the part of the dataset that is the endpoint for the main task?
I tried looking at articles, and the QMRF of multi task models, but did not find info about my question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
